# Manga about a main character who is reincarnated in ancient times and gets a system for martial arts

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, cultivation

The main character is reincarnated in ancient times where no one knows martial arts or cultivation and gets a system for martial arts. He is the son of a king but doesn't know it. He fights battles in an army.

Comment: *[Record of Wortenia War](https://wortenia.fandom.com/wiki/Light_Novel)* matches except that I haven't found indication that he is a king's son.

Comment: @Parmar Divyjeetsinh - Hi, welcome to the site. I edited your description in order to add some punctuation, but I had to guess where each sentence began and ended. If I put any full stops in the wrong place/s, please edit the question yourself to fix it.